# Estimates on a heat process with fixed boundary data and zero initial conditions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, geometric-analysis, heat-equation

Consider the following heat process:
For a given (say, smooth) domain $\Omega$ on a closed manifold $M$ we construct $p(t,x):\mathbb R_+ \times \bar\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$, so that

$$
\partial_t p(t,x) - \Delta p(t,x) = 0, \quad x\in \Omega \\
p(t,x) = 1, \quad x\in \partial \Omega \\
p(0,x) = 0, \quad x\in \Omega.
$$

In other words, we start heating up with a constant "1 - radiation" at the boundary.
I'd like to ask what are the known estimates of the form:

$$
p(t,x) \geq Expression (t,x).
$$
Is there, perhaps, a result giving the expression on the right hand side in terms of $t$ and $dist(x, \partial\Omega)$? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a nontrivial lower bound only in terms of $t$ and $dist(x,\partial\Omega)$. To see this, consider a domain with a tiny hole. In the limit when the hole shrinks to a point, the solution converges to that with no hole, i.e. the effect of the boundary condition on the boundary of the hole disappears.

Comment: OK, right, I guess these two variables are not sufficient. However, perhaps, there is also some (local) boundary measure involved...

Answer (score 0):

I'm nor aware of such an estimate, so just a guess. May be there is an estimate of the form
$$
u(x,t)\ge C_1\text{erfc}(-C_2d(x)/\sqrt t),
$$
where $d(x)=\text{dist}(x, \partial\Omega)$. When $\Omega$ is a half space it can be checked directly, using the representation of solution as a double layer potential. And in the general case local behavior of the solution near $t=0$ should be the same.

Comment: My first thoughts were exactly in this spirit. In order to produce some estimates in the general case, I suspect that boundary control is needed - you just try to cut a small piece of the radiating boundary and approximate with a flat patch, where you can predict Heat (Brownian) behaviour.